# Rolify: Can a User assign a specific Resource Role to another User?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancancan, rolify

I'm trying to determine whether this flow is possible when using Rolify (with Devise and CanCanCan)... And, if so, how it would be implemented:

I have a class, `Shop`, which belongs to `User`. I'd like the user who created a respective `Shop` instance to be able to assign a Rolify role (`:manager`) to any user (N.B. any user who created an instance should be able to assign the role - not just a user who has the role `:admin`).

I know this can be achieved via the rails console through the `add_role` command (using, as an example, a `Shop` instance with `id: 5`):

`user.add_role :manage, Shop.find(5)`

But I'm not clear on whether or not this can be done programmatically by individual users - where a user can assign the role to another user. Specifically, by selecting the user from a searchable dropdown form and assigning the role on submit.

Though I don't yet have any code that's worth showing / helpful to show, I'm hoping to get direction here as to how best to approach this issue (e.g., should the action be defined in `shops_controller.rb` or in its own controller?). Also, would it be better to scrap using Rolify for this altogether and create a join table for shops_managers?

If it helps, here's the `Ability.rb` class:

```
    class Ability
      include CanCan::Ability

      def initialize(user)
        if user
          if user.has_role? :admin
            can :manage, :all
          else
            can [:edit, :update], Shop.with_role(:manager, user)
            can :manage, Shop, :user_id => user.id
            can :manage, User, id: user.id
            can :read, :all
          end
        end
      end
```

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need join table to store shops_managers. You have a role model:
`Role(id: integer, name: string, resource_id: integer, resource_type: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)`
It is perfectly fine to add the role in shops#create doing something like:

```
if @shop.save
  #some code
  @current_user.add_role :manager, @shop  
  #some more code
end
```

If you want to manage the roles it should be done in some other controller.. probably in admins namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Anton - I moved onto another feature but will try your solution when I return to it in the coming week or two. Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks again - finally was able to revisit and can confirm the above solution works. Marking accepted.

Comment: Great! Thank you.